# Mapbox GL JS - How to check if a person is inside a certain area and then display a message if he is

Tags: geolocation, mapbox-gl-js, bounding-box

I'm trying to do a feature with Mapbox GL JS where it will first detect if the user is inside a certain location, and if he is display a HTML message to say that he is in the location.

I believe I would have to utilize the geolocatecontol feature to check where the user is, and then the bounding box feature to determine if the user is inside that location or not. Problem is, I have no idea how I would do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>mapbox-gl-js won't provide you the ability to check whether a coordinate resides within a bounding box. I'd recommend using turf.js, it provides a lot of geo helper functions, e.g. `booleanWithin(geometryA, geometryB)`</s>

**EDIT**: mapbox-gl-js actually provides a `contains(lngLat)` function on the `LngLatBounds` class: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#lnglatbounds#contains

If you have a simple rectangular bounding box, you can implement the check yourself:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190111/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle

An example using the [Geolocation.watchPosition()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition) api of the browser:

```
const southWest = new mapboxgl.LngLat(-2.488133, 53.747698);
const northEast = new mapboxgl.LngLat(-2.488156, 53.748530);

const bounds = new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds(southWest, northEast);

// called every time a new user position is determined
function checkUserPostion(position) {
  const {latitude, longitude} = position.coords;

  const isUserInBbx = bounds.contains([longitude, latitude]);

  if (isUserInBbx) {
    // update HTML
  }
}

navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(checkUserPostion);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, can you provide me with more clarification on how I could use the booleanWithin feature to achieve what I'm trying to do? Perhaps some example code?

Comment: @BroCodeNode You can use the mapboxgljs `map.getBounds()` method to get your current map extent. Then it's up to you decide which geometry hit test satisfies your requirements. You could check to see if the rectangle intersects with another rectangle, whether a geometry is fully contained by a rectangle, etc... You should be able to find all of those types of methods in the turf.js package.

Comment: I've added a code example using the browser geolocation api

Comment: @Scarysize Thanks for the help! I've attempted to follow the example you gave me but I still have no luck, this is what I've attempted. Before the code you gave me I added the following code:   var southWest = new mapboxgl.LngLat(-2.488133, 53.747698); var northEast = new mapboxgl.LngLat(-2.488156, 53.748530); var boundingBox = new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds(southWest, northEast);  I then did this: const bbox = boundingBox in an attempt to make it check against the location and finally, a simple alert to say "Test Successful" if it worked. So far I've not been able to do it.

Comment: booleanWithin expects a GeoJSON geometry, which mapbox.LngLatBounds are not. But I discovered that LngLatBounds actually has a "contains" method. I updated the code example; you won't need turf.js.

Comment: @Scarysize Thank you so much for the help, it's finally working.

Comment: Cool, feel free to accept my answer as the "correct" one, so other people can find this solution too :)

Comment: @Scarysize Done :)